# CursorAdapter get id by Cursor

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I am trying get id by Cursor in bindView ,in the CursorAdapter.
I wrote that:

```
 public void bindView(View v,Context context2,Cursor cursor) {
 super.bindView(v, context, cursor);
 long id3= cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
   . . . .
 }
```

Then i call to deleteOne:

```
     delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        mySQLiteAdapter.deleteOne(id3);
      }
 });
```

The method:

```
   public boolean deleteOne(long id) {
   return sqLiteDatabase.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id=" + id, null) > 0;
   }
```

And i did not get any error but always when i click on delete in any row, the last row(record,view) deleted instead.

Thank you and sorry about my grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Where do set the id3? in the tag of the view? because i dont see where u can get the *id3*. If you arent puting it in the *view.setTag()* and then at onClick retreivin it then that is the issue - u will always have the **last** id3 and this is why u delete the last row.
Also, I dont see any notifyDatasetChange() at our onClick...